# where is Common.Library.ProcessUtils located in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

Im new in asp.net i dont know where is  Common.Library.ProcessUtils located in asp.net C#

```
public bool IsPublicLoginID()
    {
        return GetUserType() == Common.Library.ProcessUtils.UT_Public;
    }
```